# Regex working in Regexr tool, but not in PHP

Tags: php, regex, database, preg-replace, pcre

My goal is to retrieve the alias from a join clause.

Here is my RegEx: `/(.*)rqd_evenements (?:as )([a-z_\-A-Z]+)(.*)/i`

Sample string:

> LEFT JOIN rqd_term_relationships ON (rqd_posts.ID = rqd_term_relationships.object_id) JOIN rqd_icl_translations t ON rqd_posts.ID = t.element_id AND t.element_type = CONCAT('post_', rqd_posts.post_type) INNER JOIN rqd_evenements AS ev ON ev.post_id = ID

I do a preg_replace:

```
preg_replace($regex, '$2', $sample_string);
```

This results in:

> LEFT JOIN rqd_term_relationships ON (rqd_posts.ID = rqd_term_relationships.object_id) JOIN rqd_icl_translations t ON rqd_posts.ID = t.element_id ev

Expected result: `ev`

What's puzzling me is that it is working in RegExr: https://regexr.com/46hil

Comment: It seems to be choking on "AND". If I remove it, it works as expected.

Comment: If this is db-related which seems to be, check for errors on the query. I don't know which api you're using to connect / query with (or the RDBMS), so I can't give you the right error handler for it. Enable error reporting also.

Comment: can't reproduce - http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/401fe03cd788063e77416b662cd665ebd6d1445c

Comment: Oops, there were hidden linebreaks inserted by another plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need all those capture groups.

```
/rqd_evenements (?:as )?\K[\w-]+/i
```

If you just want to extract a substring, use preg_match() as access the [0] element.

Perhaps your pattern doesn't work on your live query string because you have newline characters not being matched by the dot metacharacter.  `s` flag can fix that.

---

With preg_replace:

```
/.*rqd_evenements (?:as )?([\w-]+).*/is
```

Replace with `$1`.

Comment: I find my code more readable with a one-line preg_replace vs a simpler regex.

Comment: You're right. There was newline characters that were not visible.